# How to have a getStringExtra message before onCreate method?

Tags: java, android, json, methods, oncreate

I have two activities which in the first one I make a message and by `putExtra` I move it to next activity. But as you know to get the message in the secind activity I need to have `getStringExtra` in `onCreate` method.  In the other hand I really need to have that message before onCreate starts. So how can I have that.

```
public class Result extends Activity {
String url; // <<< I need the message to put it here

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_result);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String mainURL = intent.getStringExtra(SingleSearchPage.EXTRA_MESSAGE); // Here is the message

    url = mainURL;  //Tried to change the value of URL but did not work

    new GetJSONTask().execute(url);

}
class GetJSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {


        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
            // Creating new JSON Parser
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            return json;
        }
```

LOG:

```
    11-26 03:56:00.666: D/URL(777): url =http://api.worldbank.org/countries/CA/indicators/SP.POP.TOTL?date=1980:2013&format=json
11-26 03:56:00.796: I/Choreographer(777): Skipped 62 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-26 03:56:01.045: I/Choreographer(777): Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-26 03:56:01.316: W/dalvikvm(777): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
11-26 03:56:01.536: E/AndroidRuntime(777): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
11-26 03:56:01.536: E/AndroidRuntime(777): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-26 03:56:01.536: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
11-26 03:56:01.536: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
```

Any idea to have the value of intent message before the onCreate?

Comment: Since you're passing `url` straight to your Asynctask, just use the `urls` parameter to access the String: `JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(urls[0]);`.

Comment: @A--C So you mean I only need to change `JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);` to `JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(urls[0]);` ? If I am right, I tried it. but did not work.

Comment: Can you tell why you need it before `onCreate`. Maybe there is a better way of doing what you want..

Comment: Is the app crashing though? If it is, post the stack trace. Also, considering `onCreate()` is the first method in which an Activity is fully defined, I don't see why you need this String beforehand.

Comment: @user3026034 are you getting value in `mainURL` from previous Activiy?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK yes. I get a url which I will use that to get data by json

Comment: @AmulyaKhare the value that I get from previous activity is json url that which this current activity needs to run that url first and then get data based on that url. So I need that value before on in background to get data, not in onCreate method. Thats Why I need it.

Comment: @A--C yes then I try to access this activity is crashes and stops working. I just posted log for more info.

Comment: @A--C I believe I need it beforehand because in OnCreate method it calls `new GetJSONTask().execute(url);` Although I am not sure for my reason.

Comment: What is line 67 of your source file? It is a line pertaining to `onPostExecute()` of your Asynctask, which is housed in `SingleResult.java` (Why then, did you post the `Result` class? Does one inherit from the other? Be detailed in your question.

Comment: @A--C it is a line about array in JSON. `JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("data");` I am not sure if it is related. i noticed its working when I change the `url` to another url and not what it get from old activity. BTW sorry singleresult is the same as result i changed the name and copied parts I need on here.

Comment: @A--C it is irrelevant, I mean the line number. He is trying to parse xml using json. Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ï»¿<?xml

Comment: @user3026034 you need a xml parser not JSON!

Comment: @LazyNinja unfortunately json is my only option, cannot change it. :/

Comment: @user3026034 could you  post the string you are trying to parse?

Comment: @LazyNinja Heh, how did I miss the top line of the stack trace? That makes sense.

Comment: @LazyNinja http://api.worldbank.org/countries/ca/indicators/SP.POP.TOTL?date=2000:2008&format=json This is something that first activity makes and sends to second activity.

Comment: @user3026034, for that you need JSON. Are you sure it is the same url you have at this line JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);? Please double check!

Comment: @LazyNinja so do you believe what I did is correct? my idea was to make the url field in top, and update it after the getStringExtra is loaded. if that's correct I then I'll have to focus on other parts to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and tell me what Log.d prints out*

```
  public class Result extends Activity {
    String url; // <<< I need the message to put it here

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_result);

      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
       if (extras != null) {
          mainURL= extras.getString(SingleSearchPage.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
       }
       Log.d("URL", "url =" + mainURL);

        url = mainURL;  //Tried to change the value of URL but did not work

        new GetJSONTask().execute(url);

    }
```

Comment: I just updated the Logcat result in my first post. Please have a look.  The url that it prints out is correct. And by the way actual file name is SingleResult.

Comment: Another thing that might help you to find the solution is that, if I put this url for String url; in line 2 and basically initialise it, then comment out the inent part. It works and uses the url. e.g: `String url = "http://api.worldbank.org/countries/CA/indicators/SP.POP.TOTL?date=1980:2013&format=json"`

Comment: Try new GetJSONTask().execute(mainUrl); instead! I dont think it will change a thing a though. There is something trivial we are missing here.